# How to use the update function in 'rhash'

Tags: bash, scripts, checksums

I'm having trouble using 'rhash' to update an existing file containing md5 checksums on Ubuntu server 14.04.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo rhash -r -u --md5 /checksum/these/files --output=/checksum/these/files/checksum.md5
```

The rhash manual says that '-u' will append any new checksums onto the end of the file but when I run my bash script the output file becomes completely blank/no contents whatsoever (it even deletes previously saved checksums from the list).

Am I doing anything wrong in my script? Or am I misinterpreting the '-u' option? 
Any help you geniuses can give me would be awesome =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rhash` [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ed2k-link.1.html) states (emphasis mine):

> -u, --update
>
> Update  hash  files  specified  by  command  line.   The program
>             calculates and **appends hashes to the updated hash  file**  in  the
>             format  specified  by  formating options.  Hashes are calculated
>             for those files from the same directory as the hash file,  which
>             are yet not present in it.

So, the output is added to `/checksum/these/files` and not to `/checksum/these/files/checksum.md5`. The `/checksum/these/files/checksum.md5` file is created by the `--output` option but since you're using `-u` which means "update the original file", no output is printed there.

For example:

```
$ date > file1
$ date > file2

$ md5sum * > hashes
$ cat hashes 
909b1419ee961b556e0013929d8b667e  file1
a6de9f219de32fec651e62e3c457169e  file2

$ rhash -r -u --md5 hashes --output=new
Updated: hashes

$ cat hashes
909b1419ee961b556e0013929d8b667e  file1
a6de9f219de32fec651e62e3c457169e  file2
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  new
$ cat new
$
```

As you can see above, the file `new` was created before the rest of the command was run, so it was included in the hash check. Since there was no associated hash for `new` in `hashes`, a line was appended to the `hashes` file.

---

On a more general note, please don't use `sudo` when it isn't needed. If you really do need root access to modify `/checksum/these/files`, remove the `sudo` from the script and run the script itself with `sudo`: `sudo /path/to/script.sh`.

Comment: Thanks so much! You've saved me alot of time rehashing files that have already been hashed =]